# Xamarin Forms C# Как убрать скрол у ListView?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

Начинаю вникать в xamarin. Решил написать простенький проект а-ля заметочника. Делаю все по паттерну MVVM. Проблема следующая: нужно разместить 2 списка, слева и справа, они разных размеров, и не зависимы друг от друга, вот пока сделал примерно так:
[image: Пример]

Но суть в том, что ListView имеет в себе свой scroll, и я без понятия как его можно отключить..
наваял вообще так:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Diary.Views.NotesListPage">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="10, 20, 10, 0" />
            <On Platform="Android" Value="10, 0" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Добавить" Command="{Binding CreateNoteCommand}" />
<ScrollView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListView x:Name="NoteListLeft" ItemsSource="{Binding NotesLeft}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote, Mode=TwoWay}" HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ContentView Padding="5">
                            <Frame OutlineColor="Black"
                                   Padding="10">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <!--<BoxView Color="{Binding Color}"
                                             WidthRequest="50"
                                             HeightRequest="50"  />-->
                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                                              <Label Text="{Binding Message}" FontSize="Small" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </ContentView>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
                <ListView Grid.Column="1" x:Name="NoteListRight" ItemsSource="{Binding NotesRight}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote, Mode=TwoWay}" HasUnevenRows="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ContentView Padding="5">
                                    <Frame OutlineColor="Black"
                                       Padding="10">
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <!--<BoxView Color="{Binding Color}"
                                             WidthRequest="50"
                                             HeightRequest="50"  />-->
                                            <StackLayout>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Message}" FontSize="Small" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Frame>
                                </ContentView>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
</ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это можно реализовать путем создания собственного рендера.
В общий проект добавляете следующий класс:

```
public class CustomListview : ListView {}
```

В проект Android:

```
public class CustomListViewRenderer: ListViewRenderer 
{  
    Context _context;  
    public CustomListViewRenderer(Context context): base(context) 
    {  
        _context = context;  
    }  
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
    {  
        base.OnElementChanged(e);  
        if (Control != null) 
        {  
            Control.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Не забудьте добавить перед namespace в Android проекте

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomListview), typeof(CustomListViewRenderer))]
```

Используется в XAML так(при условии что класс CustomListview объявлен в корне общего проекта):

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Имя проекта"
<local:CustomListview></local:CustomListview>
```

Подробнее о custom renderer можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer)

Comment: не сработало, т.е. просто убрало видимость у скрола, но все равно каждый лист скролит отдельно. Я понапихал еще возможные булевскмие варианты скрола на false, но безуспешно. Как бы если в мой xaml вставить для примера label, то он нормально скролит все как одно, но вот я так понимаю, что в listView переопределение только этого свойства не отделаешься.. Видимо оно перехватывает общий скрол уже после вызова base.OnElementChanged(e);

Comment: Вам необходимо его полностью отключить?

Comment: Я так полагаю что да, т. к. я хочу чтоб эти две колонки(с разными размерами блоков) скролились только от одного внешнего скрола вдвоём одновременно, но так как у каждого свой скролл, то по разному, а внешний даже не отображается. Надеюсь более-менее понятно описал)

Comment: Без кастомного макета здесь не обойтись будет, потому что ListView не подойдёт. Вот здесь с примером описано, как создать собственный макет: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom